# Geolocation in the building outside the city

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I have the target to obtain geolocation of mobile phone, for this purpose i use three approaches:

1. Wifi geolocation if wifi access points are present.
2. GPS if satellites are visible for mobile phone.
3. Geolocation by cell towers.

I use google location api for the retrieving location by cell towers ids and BSID's of routers.

But, I have problem in particular case - my mobile phone is outside the city and wifi points are not available (first item is not appropriate), gps location also is not eligible because mobile phone is in building and signal from satellites are not available), last variant with location by cells tower works, but result has very bad accuracy (from 100m to a few km).

1. How can I improve the accuracy to a few tens of meters?
2. Can i use number of mobile phone for obtaining location of mobile phone?

Comment: is it for one particular building or it need to work for every building. If it's for one particular building, you can use ibeacon with bluethoot, but your device will need BLE

Comment: In my opinion, there is no way to increase accuracy of `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. You will always have problems within buildings/elevators or if many electronic devices are around. But I never had bad accuracy with over one kilometer?! Or are you doing any fancy calculation and ignoring the curvature of the earth?

Comment: @JCDecary thx it's good idea, i will consider it

Comment: @longilong region has limited count of cell towers (it's very far from city), my formula use amendment of signal power and my calculations consider the curvature of the earth.